# ggplot legend in R is showing extra dates between the only 2 dates in my data

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, legend

First question here and couldn't find an answer online.

I am comparing values (value at risk) between two dates, February 3, 2020 and January 21, 2020 across a few variables (trading strategies). In a bar chart, value at risk is on the y axis, trading strategies are on the x axis, and the two dates are side by side each strategy for comparison.

Problem is the legend is showing a scale of dates from Jan 21 to Feb 3, so it includes the 23rd, 25th, etc. even though these days do not exist in my dataset.

The r shiny code I am using to output this is below:

```
  output$varChart <- renderPlotly({
    ggplotly(
      ggplot(varData(),aes(fill=AsOfDate,x=TradingStrategy,y=VaR)) + 
        geom_bar(position="dodge2",alpha = 0.5,stat="identity") + 
        scale_y_continuous(labels = comma_format()) + 
        theme_ipsum(grid="XY") +
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
              axis.title.x = element_blank(),
              axis.title.y = element_blank()) +
        ggtitle("Value at Risk"))
  })
```

And here is what I get (leaving the strategy names out):

[image: Value at Risk Bar Chart]

Is there any way to get the legend to only show the two dates in the dataset instead of a color scale?

Comment: You could try setting `fill = factor(AsOfDate)` in the ggplot.

Comment: That's a good recommendation - your AsOfDate is continuous, therefore the gradient scale.